# How does promisify know which variable to return?

Tags: node.js, node-promisify

I used util.promisify on this `sqlite3` function:

```js
// Before
db.each("Select * from example;", (error, row) => console.table(row));
db.each = util.promisify(db.each);
// After
async function getRow()
     try {
        console.table(await db.each("Select * from example;")); // line 7
     } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
     }
}
```

My question is, **how does promisify know which variable (the "err" or the "row") to return in line 7?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The util.promisify() is used/able to convert a callback into promise only if the first parameter of the callback function is the error parameter.

So, it will always return "row" in Line 7. If there is an error, it will go to the catch block.

Comment: In short, promisify always expects first parameter as the error parameter.

Comment: promisify always expects the first parameter of the callback function as the error parameter, and "the callback itself" as the last parameter. For example, this **can** be promisified: `form.parse(req, (err, fields, uploads) => { //...`.